# Как заштриховать область под графиком в excel

Tags: excel, visual-basic

[image: мой график с штриховкой наложением прямоунольника]У меня есть график в Экселе. Именно график с двумя числовыми осями. Я видел как штрихуют область под графиком, когда по Оy числа, а по Ох строки. Но это не то.
Я пробовал просто фигуру прямоугольника поверх графика накладывать, но это колхозно. Может есть какой-то вариант на Visual Basic for Applications написать свою штриховку? Или он поддерживает только встроенный функционал?

Comment: Аккуратно фломастером не пробовали? :) Шутка, конечно... Но что еще можно посоветовать, когда только картинка... Как строите график, по каким данным? Хороший пример, который можно поюзать, и хорошее объяснение - половина решения.

Comment: Я же говорю, точечный график(по двум осям числа). Его нужно заштриховать.